# reading xml files in vb6

Tags: xml, vb6

I know it is easier to read xml files in vb.net but since our appl is still on vb6, i need a work around. but somehow, i am stuck. also i do not have control over the xml file as it is being generated from another application. Short code from the xml file is below,

```
    <Report>
           <Categories>
                   <Category name="CASHMAN" value="Cash Management" />
                   <Category name="IM" value="Inventory Management" />
                   <Category name="POS" value="Point of Sale" />
                   <Category name="PRODUCT" value="Product" />
           </Categories>
    </Report>
```

If the XML file would have been in a format like this, i would have been able to read it easily.

```
    <Report>
           <Categories>
                   <name>CASHMAN</name>
                   <value>Cash Management</value>
           </Categories>
           <Categories>
                   <name>IM</name>
                   <value>Inventory Management</value>
           </Categories>
           <Categories>
                   <name>POS</name>
                   <value>Point of Sale</value>
           </Categories>
           <Categories>
                   <name>PRODUCT</name>
                   <value>Product</value>
           <Categories>
    <Report>
```

But since the xml file generated is not in my control, i m stuck up this since couple of hours now.

i need to read the NAME-VALUE pairs from this xml file. how do i go about with this?

please help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do it with [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(v=VS.85).aspx), which offers similar functionality as some of the .NET XML APIs. I don't have a copy of VB6 right now, but it's pretty easy. First, add a reference to [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx) from you VB6 project. You would then do something like the following:

- Create an instance of [MSXML2.DOMDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756987(v=VS.85).aspx)
- Call the [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722(v=VS.85).aspx) method to parse the XML file
- Call the `selectNodes("/Report/Categories/Category")`. This will return an [IXMLDOMNodeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757073(v=VS.85).aspx) object.
- You can then loop through the node list retrieving each [IXMLDOMNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765513(v=VS.85).aspx) via [item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757028(v=VS.85).aspx) or [nextNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757831(v=VS.85).aspx).
- You can then get the `name` and `value` using the [`attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760261(v=VS.85).aspx) property of the XMLDOMNode or using `selectSingleNode("@name").Text` and `selectSingleNode("@value").Text`

MSXML is fairly flexible, so there is even shorter syntax that you can use, but the above should work out for you. If you have not already figured it out, I will post the code when I get to a machine with VB6 installed.

**UDPATE:**

Here is a working example using the XML sample you provided.

```
Sub ParseXmlDocument()
   Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
   Dim success As Boolean

   success = doc.Load(App.Path & "\test.xml")
   If success = False Then
      MsgBox doc.parseError.reason
   Else
      Dim nodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

      Set nodeList = doc.selectNodes("/Report/Categories/Category")

      If Not nodeList Is Nothing Then
         Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
         Dim name As String
         Dim value As String

         For Each node In nodeList
            ' Could also do node.attributes.getNamedItem("name").text
            name = node.selectSingleNode("@name").Text
            value = node.selectSingleNode("@value").Text
         Next node
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [MSXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-in-vba) as advised in this question (and in the article linked by Ardman).

You can use [IXMLDOMElement.getAttributeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764650(VS.85).aspx) to read attributes.

For example this code below reads the [sample books.xml file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=VS.85).aspx) from MSDN and accesses an attribute. You need a reference to [a version of Microsoft XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254869/which-version-of-microsoft-xml-msxml-dll-to-reference-in-my-vb6-project).

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Dim nodeBook As IXMLDOMElement
Dim nodeId As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim sIdValue As String
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.Load App.Path & "\books.xml"
If (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
   Dim myErr
   Set myErr = xmlDoc.parseError
   MsgBox ("You have error " & myErr.reason)
Else
   Set nodeBook = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//book")
   Set nodeId = nodeBook.getAttributeNode("id")
   sIdValue = nodeId.xml
   MsgBox sIdValue
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could uses XSLT to transform the XML from this structure to value pair

http://www.xmlfiles.com/articles/sample_chapters/sams_xmlforaspnet/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this questions answers helped me a lot. Took me 2 days to figure how,

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")

Dim nodeBook
Dim nodeId
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.Load ("xmlfile url")
If (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
   Dim myErr
   Set myErr = xmlDoc.parseError
   MsgBox ("You have error " & myErr.reason)
Else
   Set nodeBook = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//Program")
   Set nodeId = nodeBook.getAttributeNode("description")
   wscript.Echo nodeId.value
End If
```

Comment: It's better if you can explain your code at least a bit when you are posting a code as your answer.

Comment: oh sorry my bad, i fetch xml file from url and store some data from it for later use, i had problems accessing the values like <program program-name="Walking Dead"></program> but was able to get the data which was just stored in <Program>value</Program> this is the key what i was missing "getAttributeNode("")"