# how to load XML file in VB6

Tags: xml, vb6

** I have a XML file in C:\sample project VB6\XMLFile1.xml but i dont know to fetch XML file in VB6, below i write a code in c# its executing **

```
          private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this code is for keypress event handler 
        string path;
        path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        myxml.Load(@"" + path + "/samplexml.xml");





        XmlNode first = myxml.SelectSingleNode("students/student");

        name.Text = first.SelectSingleNode("s_name").InnerText;

        age.Text = first.Attributes["s_age"].Value;

        gender.Text = myxml.SelectSingleNode("students/student/s_gender").InnerText;
        addres.Text = myxml.SelectSingleNode("students/student/s_addres").InnerText;
        phone.Text = myxml.SelectSingleNode("students/student/s_phone").InnerText;

        previus.Visible = false;

        //this code take all the nodelist to the collection list 

        items = new List<XmlNode>();
        XmlNodeList xy = myxml.SelectNodes("students/student");
        foreach (XmlNode item in xy)
        {
            items.Add(item);
            size++;
        }
```

Comment: please anyone help me out

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870485/reading-xml-files-in-vb6